# Cannot chown /media/daily directory

Tags: umount

I created a /media/daily directory on  which a USB key is mounted for a small daily backup by user's crontab. But it is now owned by root rather than user:

```
$ ls -la /media | grep daily
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   40960 Dec 31  1969 daily
$ mount | grep daily
/dev/sdc1 on /media/daily type vfat
(rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,
  shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
```

I cannot write to the key because daily is owned by root. But I can't change ownership of daily because "Operation not permitted"

```
$ sudo chown haines:haines /media/daily
chown: changing ownership of '/media/daily': Operation not permitted
```

I cannot umount the key because it it busy:

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sdc1
umount: /media/daily: target is busy.
```

I do lsof:

```
$ sudo lsof /media/daily
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc \
    Output information may be incomplete. \
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME \
bash     8310 haines  cwd    DIR   8,33    40960    1 /media/daily \
bash    10265   root  cwd    DIR   8,33    40960    1 /media/daily \
lsof    10683   root  cwd    DIR   8,33    40960    1 /media/daily \
lsof    10684   root  cwd    DIR   8,33    40960    1 /media/daily
```

A kill of the two bash processes has no effect. They can't be killed it seems.

How can I change ownership of /media/daily or delete it if I cannot prevent the directory from being busy?

Answer (score 0):

To disconnect a busy device immediately you can do:

`umount -l /PATH/OF/BUSY-DEVICE`

**NOTE:**
These commands can disrupt a running process, cause data loss OR corrupt open files.You should not run the above command when inside the mounted path (Folder/Drive/Device) itself. You need to change the path first with `cd` command and then run the above command.